# How to build a deployment Pipeline Using Bitbucket, Jenkins and ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, bitbucket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We want to deploy our Java application war from Jenkins to AWS Cloud. 
Actually, we are doing manual deployments these days. We would like to build a deployment pipeline using Bitbucket, Jenkins and ElasticBeanstalk.

Can anyone guide me through the steps that needs to be taken to make it all work.

Comment: You might also want to consider using CodeDeploy for the actual deployment step in your pipeline.

Comment: i think this question with _"[how to] make it all work"_ is a bit too broad for here atm. What steps have you taken so far to achieve what you want?

Comment: Thanks for you valuable suggestion Gerold. Actually, I'm very new to Jenkins/Bitbucket. We used to deploy all that manually. Just wanted to know how all these things work together and makes this whole process automated.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at http://awsdqs.com/. This guide walks you through setting up a CI environment with AWS Beanstalk.